# How to Get to All Applications Screen on OLPC?

Tags: fedora

I am interesting in developing for the OLPC platform and currently installed an OLPC emulation on VMWare on my Windows 7 (the image is Soas-v3-Mirabelle).

I am trying to get to the view all applications screen (the screen where you see neighborhood view, home, journal, and all open applications' icons on the top). I have included picture reference below:

[image] [image]

The OLPC has a dedicated hardware button to do this. How do I get to this screen on my Windows 7 emulation?